# proving $f$ and $g$ are constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be entire functions such that $e^f + e^ g=1$ then how to show $f$ and $g$ are constant.
I am having trouble in proving these. any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $e^f\ne 0$ and hence $e^g\ne 0$ and $1$ - Contradicts Picard's Little Theorem.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I have another question.I think it ia true.Is it?

Comment: Let f and g be entire functiona such that (f•g)(z) is a polynomial .I think both f and g are polynomials .